# How to enable React routing in IIS?

Tags: reactjs, iis, routes

The following component is loaded from App.js of my React application.

```
const Main = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/:userid" component={Banks} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

When the application is run using local development server, I am able to get userid from the following url:

http://myAppPath/100

However, when I build the application and host it in IIS, I am not able to get the userid.

https://localhost/Bank/100 --> UPDATED HTTP TO HTTPS

The routing is not recognized. I used URL Rewrite but the value of userid is still not coming in.

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Routing" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no"><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"><link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json"><link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico"><title>Bank App</title><link href="./static/css/main.b730bb13.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="./static/js/main.2564873f.js"></script></body></html>
```

Comment: add your build `index.html` unminified to this question

Comment: there is no base tag in your html

Answer (score 5):

install iis url rewrite on your server first from [here](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite). 
then only it respects your url re-write config

*UPDATE*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Static Assets" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="([\S]+[.](html|htm|svg|js|css|png|gif|jpg|jpeg))" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/{R:1}"/>
        </rule>
        <rule name="ReactRouter Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I have installed iis url rewrite. I wrote the rule only through IIS Manager.

Comment: are you getting 404 error or server errors when you access these urls ?

Comment: 404 - File or directory not found.

Comment: It still gives - 404 - File or directory not found.

Comment: your app needs to be on the root folder. and it must have index.html file.

Comment: Yes, the app points to the build folder I created using npm run build

Comment: have you given `<base href='/app-path' />` in your index.html ?

Comment: I added "homepage": "." in package.json
UPDATE
but not <base href='/app-path' /> in index.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181879/discussion-between-mak-and-hannad-rehman).